# Replace probability mass function with continuous argument for asymptotic: how to reinterpret

Tags: probability

I'd like some help reinterpreting the asymptotic result on a pmf. The asymptotic result is a continuous function, whereas the mass function is discrete.

Say $P(Y(t)=k)=f(k,t)$. It is the case that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}f(k,t)=0$. I want to know how the tail of the distribution decays for long times, so I let $k=e^{b t}$, with $0<b<1$. This gives
\begin{equation}
P(Y(t)=e^{b t})=g(t)+O(e^{-b t})
\end{equation}
where $g(t)$ is the leading order term. For example take
\begin{equation}
P(Y(t)=k)=\frac{(1-e^{-t})^{k}}{k t}
\end{equation}
then making the substitution we have
\begin{gather}
P(Y(t)=e^{b t})=e^{-bt}t^{-1}+O(e^{-t}t^{-1}).
\end{gather}
What can we say about the original mass function from this?

Comment: Where "$g(t)$ is the leading order term" of exactly what?

Comment: Of the mass function with respect to $t$. I've edited to give an example.